# Multiplying fields from separate columns which have the same ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, multiplication

I have two tables which are joined by an ID...

table 1

```
- Assessment ID 
- Module ID 
- Assessment Weighting
```

table 2

```
- ID 
- AssessmentID
- ModuleID
- UserID
- MarkFrom100
```

An assessment can have many students taking the assessment. 
For example
A module has two assessments, one worth 60% and the other worth 40%. in table 2, I want to take the weighting value from table 1 and multiply it against the mark from 100.

```
SELECT * FROM Assessment, ModuleAssessmentUser WHERE 
INNER JOIN moduleassementuser.assessmentID on Assessment.assessmentID
MULTIPLY AssessmentWeighting BY MarkFrom100 AS finalmark
UserID = 1
```

I know this is way off, but I really don't know how else to go about it.

My SQL knowledge is limited, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want the values for a particular module, or do you want it for all modules?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?'

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Also please add the queries you've already tried.

Comment: @Sirmyself for a particular module, if that makes sense

Comment: it does, I am building an answer that was potentially using a `where`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @Sirmyself i tried to edit my answer there to show what I have tried

Comment: `WHERE 
INNER JOIN ` is wrong. The `JOIN` operator is part of the `FROM` clause, not part of the `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `SUM` function in your query which will sum all the data of a certain group in a sub query wich will allow you to multiply the sum to the weight

sub query :

```
SELECT ModuleID, AssessmentID, UserID, SUM(MarkFrom100) as Total
    FROM Table_2
    GROUP BY ModuleID
```

Then use this sub query as a table in a main query :

```
SELECT T1.Assessment_ID, T1.ModuleID, Q1.UserID (Q1.Total * T1.Assessment_Weighting) as FinalMark
    FROM (SELECT ModuleID, UserID, SUM(MarkFrom100) as Total
              FROM Table_2
              GROUP BY ModuleID) AS Q1
    INNER JOIN Table_1 as T1 on T1.ModuleID = Q1.ModuleID
--  WHERE T1.ModuleID = 2  -- a particular module ID
    GROUP BY ModuleID;
```

Note that the `WHERE` statement is in comment. If you want the whole data, remove it, if you want a particular data, use it ^^

---

## NOTE :

I don't have your database, so it may need some tweeks, but the main idea is there